# Reset Internet Explorer security zone to default level

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, security

Is there an API or whatever which can reset `Internet` zone to its default value (like the arrow).

I didn't find any method in IInternetZoneManager interface to do that.

[image: Internet Explorer security zones]

Comment: In general, if you run this in a consumer machine, you should make it very clear in a dialogue box that you've done this, and why. Generally, tampering with these settings silently is a big no-no (though I can think of some contexts in a business environment where it would be useful).

Comment: Yeah, this will be clearly mentionned to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to change registry settings from your code.
This would be a good place to start:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones[Zone Number]
```

Zone numbers are:
0 = My Computer
1 = Local
2 = Trusted Sites
3 = Internet
4 = Restricted

You may have to copy the value of DWORD RecommendedLevel to that of CurrentLevel for Internet Zone 3 (which is Internet zone).

Reference: [Internet Explorer security zones registry entries for advanced users](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569)

---

Have you tried using [IInternetZoneManager::CopyTemplatePoliciesToZone method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa359120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using dwTemplate equal to 0x00011000 which is the Recommended level?

Comment: I just managed to use this API. Works great! http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/IInternetZoneManager.html